# Wordpress comments on a separate page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments

I have a wordpress website which contains many controversial topics. The problem is that the comments become really so long that the scroll bar becomes really small, which is annoying for the reader and gives the impression that the page requires endless reading, which is not attractive.

Is there a way to show comments on a separate page, or at least have the comments show up after clicking on some button. And must this be theme-dependent? I currently use twenty-fourteen theme, but a general solution would be nice. I'm wishing there's a plugin that would do the job, but I couldn't find any. Please assist.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing an infinite scroll where more elements load via AJAX as you scroll down a page?

Comment: @RDrazard Unfortunately infinite scroll has compatibility problems with ShareThis, which I use. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is a plugin called "Hide Show Comment". It simply adds the magic, with which you can press a simple button and show the comments.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-show-comment/

The only annoying thing I found with it is that you have to purchase it in order to change the number of comments you show per click. However, I don't think  5$ is too much. It's very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://disqus.com/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/

You can get a button that loads more comments, offload comments to their server to reduce the load on your host, require a login to comment, and more.

Comment: I will try it and let you know whether it helps. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it. It's very not convenient and makes things work their way. I'll post the better solution I found. Sorry!